# pyokx python wrapper for OKX API not giving a response

Tags: python

My code is as follows:

```
from pyokx import OKXClient, Account, Trade, Marketdata
# create the base client:
client = OKXClient(
    key = 'KEY',
    secret = 'SECRET',
    passphrase = 'PASS'
)
market = Marketdata(client)
okx_ticker = market.get_ticker("BTC-USDT")
print(okx_ticker)
```

This prints `APIReturn(response=<Response [200]>)` when I should be getting the response detailed [here(docs)](https://www.okx.com/docs-v5/en/#rest-api-market-data-get-ticker).

I haven't tried anything as I'm unsure where to begin. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, is anyone able to clarify?

Comment: You're just printing the wrong thing.  You don't want to print the response object itself -- you want to print the _data attributes_ of the response.  Unfortunately I don't know exactly how to do that; the API documentation seems to be missing that simple bit of information.

Comment: Try this: `print(dir(okx_ticker))` to see all the available attributes on the response object.  Hopefully one of those is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to John Gordon's comments I was able to find the data I wanted using:

```
okx_ticker.response.content
```

Answer (score 0):

The APIReturn object is a wrapper around the raw response which exists to conveniently convert the `data` property of the JSON response to dataframe. The OKX REST API returns JSON for all endpoints, so to  get the raw JSON as a dictionary, you can use `okx_ticker.response.json()`.

The [readme](https://github.com/nicelgueta/pyokx) shows how to get the response and the dataframe, but admittedly I could have made it more obvious that the response property of the APIReturn is the underlying `requests.Response` object. You can then call `.json()`, `.text`, `.status_code` or even `.content` etc. on this object.

Thanks for trying it out and please feel free to add any issues to the GitHub repository.